# Filtering rows within datasets by running multiple search

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to create a function that can give me the possibility to filter rows within a dataset, then to create a new filtered dataset which includes only those rows (and all columns) from the original dataset, or, in case I do not want to filter them, returning my original dataset(s).
Sample of datasets are the following (same columns names, but different values in rows):

(1)

```
Name        Surname      Email                    City
Mary Jane     Koci      m.jane98@hotmail.com        NA
Luke           G.       l.girona@gmail.co.uk       London
...
```

(2)

```
Name        Surname      Email                    City
Mary         Peps      mary-peps_2@gmail.com      Madrid
Kate        Dickson    kat_son321@gmail.com       Lisbon
...
```

What I have done is the following:

```
list_datasets=[]

for i in range(0,2): # I have two datasets that I want to check individually. For each of them, I need to specify key words to filter: key word 'Mary' from the first dataset; key words ' Kim Jun' from the second dataset, ...

    key_words = [] 

    while True:
        words = input("Search: ")

        if query!='-0':
            key_words.append(words)
            df[str(i)]["Key_Word"]= df[str(i)].Names.str.contains('|'.join(key_words), case=False, regex=True)
            df[str(i)].loc[df[str(i)]["Key_Word"] != False]
        elif words=='-0':
            break
        filt=df[str(i)][df[str(i)]["Key_Word"] != False].copy()
        list_datasets.append(filt)
```

I am having some issues when I do not want to check any value from one or more datasets, i.e. when I want to keep the original dataset. 
The error, when I try to print the datasets:

```
for i in range(0,2):
    print(list_datasets[i])
```

is the following:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-e490745a8a26> in <module>
     26 
     27 for i in range(0,2):
    ---> 28     print(list_datasets[i])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am using csv files only.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**Update**

The logic should be the following. For each dataset:

- choose if to filter it or not (Y/N);
- if I select y, then I need to choose the key words to filter rows. Then return the filtered dataset;
- if I select n, then my filtered dataset should be equal to the original dataset.

Please let me know if this does not make sense and you need more info. Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using loc() to filter your dataframe by named columns with values matching your search values as regular expressions? You could create a new dataframe from your original dataframe using loc() and copy().

Comment: Hi BaloonRM. I used loc() and copy() in my code to create a new dataframe from my original one (for each dataset; I do not want a unique dataset, but one for each dataset/csv file). Do you mean this?

Comment: Where df is your original dataframe and dfcopy is the filtered copy and searchstr is a search string, something like: dfcopy = df.loc[df['Key_Word] == searchstr].copy() I've used simple string equivalence, but it could be extended to contains.

Comment: Should it work also with `df[str(i)]` where `i` run from `1` to `n` (`i` is an index for my datasets)? I had some issues with this in the past.

Comment: I've never used a list of dataframes, but it might work better to iterate over the datafame list than to iterate with an index. Something like for dfi in list_datasets: where dfi is the ith dataframe. This would remove the confusion of having the index to contend with. You could also presumably .append() each dfi copy to an output list of dataframes.

Comment: Thank you BalooRM. Unfortunately I am not fully understanding what you suggest. Sorry

Comment: I'll answer below with some example code that illustrates what I was describing with respect to filtering dataframes. It does not contain reading from csv files, the Y/N control logic, or the function construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some example code that filters pandas dataframes in the manner that I was describing in the comments above. The particular use case is to search 2 dataframes in a list for a list of values (your Key_Words). I made up 2 example dataframes and used your columns.

This is not a complete answer to all aspects of your question, but I hope that it will set you on a course to a complete solution.

```
import pandas as pd

list_datasets = []

# data in the form of list of tuples 
data1 = [('Peter', 'Smith', 'peters@example.com', 'Calgary'), 
         ('Riff', 'Jones', 'riffj@example.com', 'Ontario'), 
         ('John', 'Brown', 'johnb@example.com', 'Manitoba'),
         ('Michel', 'Boudreaux', 'michelb@example.com', 'Montreal')]

data2 = [('Sven', 'Erikson', 'svene@example.com', 'Omaha'), 
         ('Mary', 'Brown', 'maryb@example.com', 'Chicago'), 
         ('Erik', 'Svenson', 'eriks@example.com', 'Dallas'),
         ('Cindy Lou', 'Who', 'cindylouw@example.com', 'Whoville')]

# create DataFrame using data 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns =['Name', 'Surname', 'Email', 'City'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns =['Name', 'Surname', 'Email', 'City'])

print("Dataframe1:\n", df1)
print("Dataframe2:\n", df2)

list_datasets.append(df1)
list_datasets.append(df2)
# print out complete dataframes in list
# for dfi in list_datasets:
#     print("Input dataset contains:\n", dfi)

searchfield = "City"
searchlist = ['Ontario', 'Manitoba', 'Chicago', 'Dallas']
searchstr = "|".join(searchlist)
print("We will be searching for the following values:\n", searchstr)

dfout = []
for dfi in list_datasets:
    dfcopy = dfi.loc[dfi[searchfield].str.contains(searchstr, case=False, regex=True)]
    dfout.append(dfcopy)

for dfi in dfout:
    print("Result from dataset:\n", dfi)
```

Output:

```
Dataframe1:
      Name    Surname                Email      City
0   Peter      Smith   peters@example.com   Calgary
1    Riff      Jones    riffj@example.com   Ontario
2    John      Brown    johnb@example.com  Manitoba
3  Michel  Boudreaux  michelb@example.com  Montreal
Dataframe2:
         Name  Surname                  Email      City
0       Sven  Erikson      svene@example.com     Omaha
1       Mary    Brown      maryb@example.com   Chicago
2       Erik  Svenson      eriks@example.com    Dallas
3  Cindy Lou      Who  cindylouw@example.com  Whoville
We will be searching for the following values:
 Ontario|Manitoba|Chicago|Dallas
Result from dataset:
    Name Surname              Email      City
1  Riff   Jones  riffj@example.com   Ontario
2  John   Brown  johnb@example.com  Manitoba
Result from dataset:
    Name  Surname              Email     City
1  Mary    Brown  maryb@example.com  Chicago
2  Erik  Svenson  eriks@example.com   Dallas
```

Comment: Thank you so much BalooRM. I am going to figure it out how to apply to my case. Thank you for your time and answer.

Comment: You're welcome. You will also note that I commented out the code (for dfi in list_datesets:) that addresses the error message that you got from iterating as "for i in range(0,2)."